# Check if a BsonValue is not null

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, bson

Take for example the following extract from a mongo collection :

```
{"IsBasedOnProduct" : {
        "CodeUV" : "09184",
        "Name" : null,
        "pricingVersion" : "B"
    }
}
```

I would like to extract the `Name` field from this collection and put it in a C# object. But i do not know how to manage the `null` value.

This is what I am doing in my C# application :

```
if (foo.Contains("IsBasedOnProduct"))
{
    fooToExcel.Name = foo["IsBasedOnProduct"].AsBsonDocument.Contains("Name") ? foo["IsBasedOnProduct"]["Name"].AsString : string.Empty;
}
```

Of course when the `Name` is `null`, i throw an `System.ArgumentNullException`
How can I fix it in order to put `string.Empty` when the value is `null` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fix it using the following snapshot of code :

```
if (foo.Contains("IsBasedOnProduct") && foo["IsBasedOnProduct"].BsonType != BsonType.Null)
{
    fooToExcel.Name = foo["IsBasedOnProduct"].AsBsonDocument.Contains("Name")&& foo["IsBasedOnProduct"]["Name"].BsonType != BsonType.Null ? 
                        foo["IsBasedOnProduct"]["Name"].AsString : string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[@Xavier W answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44001160/1908296) correct Also there another solution to check was `BsonValue` is `NULL` using `IsBsonNull` property **[since MongoDB.Bson version 2.3.0]**

Here solution:

```cs
if (foo.Contains("IsBasedOnProduct") && !foo["IsBasedOnProduct"].IsBsonNull)
{
    fooToExcel.Name = (foo["IsBasedOnProduct"].AsBsonDocument.Contains("Name") && !foo["IsBasedOnProduct"]["Name"].IsBsonNull) ? 
                        foo["IsBasedOnProduct"]["Name"].AsString : string.Empty;
}
```

Documention for `IsBsonNull` Property -> https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.3/apidocs/html/P_MongoDB_Bson_BsonValue_IsBsonNull.htm

Answer (score -1):

Before that you have to Convert BJson to  JSON, check after the conditions.